# Generate clang compilation database for a Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, clang

Visual Studio was added a lot of support for Clang.

I want to use clang-tidy.exe for a Visual-Studio project. In order to do that I need the JSON "compilation database".

Is there some way to export this database from a visual studio (2015) project?

Comment: Any updates on this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To export the JSON compilation Database you can use the Clang Power Tools VS extension.

All you need to do is to select your VS project from Solution Explorer, open the context menu by pressing right-click on it, and then search for Clang Power Tools. In the submenu search for the **Export Compilation Database** option. The JSON compilation database will be automatically generated for you.

More details about this feature can be found in [this article](https://clangpowertools.com/blog/generate-json-compilation-database.html).

The extension is compatible with Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019.

Answer (score 5):

I've bumped into your question whilst [searching for an answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/bcifdw/lsp_clangd_windows_10) to this very problem. This is what I have found so far:

- SourceTrail provides a [Visual Studio extension](https://www.sourcetrail.com/blog/export_clang_compilation_database_from_visual_studio_solution) which is able to create a compilation database. See also [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6o7uh8/how_to_export_a_clang_compilation_database_from_a). I have no experience with the extension, but it seems to tackle this problem.
- [compdb](https://github.com/Sarcasm/compdb) is a python script with all sorts of utilities for compilation databases. AFAIK it does not yet support visual studio, but it would be a great place to add support for this functionality.

HTH.